# Junit 4 is not picking up my @Before & @After methods

Tags: java, junit, allure

My @Before and @After methods are not picking up by Junit

```
public class TestSetup {

    @Before
    public void browserSetUp() {
     // code for before a test
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
      // code after a test
    }
}
```

In Another class file I have defined

```
public class Steps{

@Step
public void step1() {
//Code for step 1

}

@Step
public void step2() {
// Code for Step 2

}

}
```

Finally I am calling those steps for my Test

```
public class Tests {

Steps step = new Steps();   

@Test
public void TC_0001 {
step.step1();
step.step2();

}


}
```

`@Test` method are getting executed but the `@Before` and `@After` methods are not executing before @Test method.Do I have to include the `TestSetup` class to somewhere ? Any help will be appreciated.

**Thought 1: As I am using Maven to build, my `@Before` `@After` methods resides in a class (`TestSetup`.java - Name is not ending with `*Test.java` and may be thats why Maven is not picking it up for execution?

Answer (score 1):

`@Before` and `@After` are used in the same class that your test is running. You should put this methods on your test class:

```
public class Tests {

    Steps step = new Steps();   

    @Test
    public void TC_0001 {
        step.step1();
        step.step2();
    }

    @Before
    public void browserSetUp() {
        // code for before a test
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // code after a test
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of putting everything in the same class `(@Test, @Before & @After)`, is there any way I can defined in another class like `TestSetup` ? Then inherit from `TestSetup` in `Tests` class ?

Answer (score 0):

`@Before` and `@After` are only executed before a single test, if they are defined in the same class as the `@Test`. In your case, the `TestSetup` class contains no tests. So either you let `Test` inherit from `TestSetup` or you create a [rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules) that is executed "around" your test.

Comment: So if I inherit the methods of TestSetup by doing following `public class Test s extends TestSetup { @Test public void TC_0001 { // code } }` Its still not wokring